# Is there any simpler way to see if a field has a certain value?

Tags: sqlite

To see if there is a Todd in my database I currently do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name='Todd' LIMIT 1
```

I then check the Cursor to see if its size == 1.  Is there a way to return a 0 or 1 from the select statement if the condition is false or true, rather than a list of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) it_exists
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE name = 'Todd'
   LIMIT 1
) q;
```

An inner select guarantees that `LIMIT` is applied. Meaning if you have hypothetically thousands of matching rows database engine will stop and return results after the first one instead of going through all of them.

Output

```
| it_exists |
|-----------|
|         1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ec7d2/8)** demo

Comment: My SQLite skills are a bit weak, what purpose does 'name_exists' and 'q' have?  It appears to work without either

Comment: `name_exists`, or rather `it_exists` in the updated version of the answer, is a column alias so that you can read it as any other column in your client code. `q` is a an alias for the subquery (inner select). It's a good practice to have one (some database systems like MySQL or SQLServer throw an exception if you don't have one). It can be named however you want of course.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the follow up, your answer is very helpful :)